# Is it possible with enough information to reverse a hash?

Tags: math, hash, cryptography, theory

I understand that hashes are not reversible by simply using math on the generated number, but I'm wondering if it would be possible with enough information to successfully reverse a hash and accurately regain the information I started with.

For example, I have a file and I run it through `md5()`, and got `6513F99D206D8714EA9EAA4A1EEA8538`, then I add some predictable garbage to the bottom of the file and run it again to get `CBB04474C52FF68F6B2AC38A9A8356A5`.

Since I have two different checksums from the same file, and I know exactly what the garbage at the end of the file is, would it now be enough information to narrow down the possible answers to just one?

Obviously this isn't practical for security, but I'm extremely curious about this specific scenario and whether there is (or ever could be) enough information to mathematically reverse a hash.

Comment: *"would it now be enough information to narrow down the possible answers to just one?"* - what exactly do you want to figure out? If the file content is known and the garbage is known then what's the objective?

Comment: @Artjom B. Ultimately, I'm wondering if accurately reversing a hash through mathematics is ever possible. I guess it's not really about the information contained in the hash, just the fact that it could be recovered.

Comment: I would say, it's not feasibly possible, but that probably depends on the hash function. If you have a specific hash function in mind and a clear problem statement, then you can ask on [crypto.se].

Comment: Hashes are lossy, regardless how much MB you feed in, the output will always of the same size. So there cannot be an mathematical exact way to get back the original value, there are infinite possible files resulting in the same hash. What you can do is brute-forcing, and hoping that you found the real file when you found a match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the basics. If the file is longer than the hash, then it contains more information than the hash, and you can't restore it from a single hash. If it is shorter, and you know that fact, then in theory you can restore it, e.g. by trying all possible files up to that length. It's probable you'll only have one match.

To be more precise, you don't have to talk about file length, but entropy. If you know the file is just printable letters, that rules out many candidates. If it's readable text, then even more so. So the general rule is that you can hope to recover the file if its entropy is smaller than that of the hash. And you have to know that this is really the case else you can't in good faith rule out the possibility of a longer file leading to the same hash.

All of he above talks about a single hash. Now you append garbage and compute another hash. Which at the most will double the amount of information contained in the hash. After that it's the same game. You can't expect to restore more information than can be contained in two hashes. Which usually isn't much.

Comment: _"If the file is longer than the hash, then it contains more information than the hash, and you can't restore it from a single hash."_ This argument sounds obvious but is shaky when generalized. Most files are also longer than their ZIP-compressed counterpart, but the latter contains the same (or even more) information.

Comment: @Dubu: You are right: I deliberately over-simplified to get the core message accross. That's why the second paragraph makes this more precise by talking about entropy. And even then, all of the above is subject to some implied “in general”, since afaik. there is no theory to rule out the possibility of some specific hash value having only a single preimage no matter the input length, even though I consider this *very* unlikely. But hash distribution in the space of length-constrained inputs might be skewed as well, so yes, the above is not precise but tries to be accessible. White lies.

Answer (score 1):

The currently accepted answer is not precisely right. The real answer is that *it depends*.

First, recall that a hash function maps from the set of all binary sequences to a finite set, typically the set of sequences of a fixed length, which is called the *hash length*. Therefore this function cannot be 1-to-1 - that is, there must be *some* output of the function to which multiple inputs get mapped. So in general there cannot be an algorithm that maps a hash to the input that generated that hash because this process is not well-defined (there is no unambiguous answer).

Fortunately you are asking about reversing the hash function for a *particular input* so it may in fact be possible. While a hash function is not 1-to-1, there could be a certain output that only one input maps to. If your input is one such input, you are in luck and a brute force algorithm that enumerates all binary strings, hashes each, and outputs the first binary string that hashes to the correct value would return the correct answer. It's also possible that you have some additional information about the input. For example, you might know that it's grammatical English text or a valid HTML document. Even if there are multiple inputs that map to the given hash value, it's possible that only one input of the correct format and of a size that fits on your hard drive maps to that hash value. In the ideal case, you have a collection of candidate files that you know your file was among - in this case almost certainly at most one hashes to the given value and hashing each such file until the hash matches the correct value would yield the correct answer.

The bad news is that while it *may* be possible to invert the hash value in theory, cryptographic hash functions have been designed to make this process brutally inefficient. If you are unable to narrow down the input space to something small, you will probably have to run a massive brute force process that won't complete before the heat death of the universe.